# cancelAnimationFrame for Animation on Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

Hello I'm trying to create a rectangle that grows from the side of the canvas until it fills the whole canvas, once it has done that shrink back to is original state, the approach I'm taking is using requestAnimationFrame /cancelAnimationFrame for some reason I'm not sure cancelAnimationFrame does not seem to work my code is the following one :

```
<script>

  function grRectangle(){

                    var canvas = document.getElementById("paper");
                    var context= canvas.getContext("2d");
                    //var forpi = Math.PI * 2;

                  //context.fillStyle = "black";
                  context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                  var posX = 200;
                  var posY = 100;
                  var color = 0;

                  function draw(){

                  context.fillStyle = 'hsl('+  color++ + ',100%,50%)';
                  context.beginPath();
                  context.rect(0,0,posX,posY);
                  context.fill();

                  posX = posX +  0.9;
                  posY = posY + 0.9;
                  if(posX < canvas.width ){

                   requestAnimationFrame(draw);
                  }  if (posX >= canvas.width){
                     posX = posX -  0.9;
                   posY = posY - 0.9;
                    cancelAnimationFrame(draw);

                  }     


    }

  draw();

  };


</script>

<body  onload= "grRectangle();" >
  <h1>Growing Rectangle</h1>
  <canvas id = "paper" width="800" height="600">


  </canvas>
```

Any help is kindly appreciatted

Comment: You described what your code is supposed to do, but you forgot to describe the actual behavior: what is it doing instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like the code you wrote doesn't actually need a cancelAnimationFrame. I am not sure what you think it does exactly, but it seems like you misunderstood it.

The cancelAnimationFrame method is used to prevent a previous call to requestAnimationFrame from getting executed, as long as this didn't happen yet. There are really few situations where you need this.

In your case I would put that growth-per-frame constant of `0.9` into a variable. When the rectangle size reaches the upper bound, just change it to `-0.9` and it will get smaller again. When it reaches the lower bound, change it again to `0.9` and it will grow again.

You will, however, not see that shrinking, because you aren't erasing your canvas. Every frame is drawn on top of the previous one. You will have to erase your canvas at the beginning of your drawing loop. To do that, move the code which fills the canvas with a black rectangle into the drawing loop (remember to set the fill-style to black).